# Prestashop: How to see and update customer phone numbers from administration panel?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Using Prestashop v1.6.1.4, by default it is configured to require customers to enter a phone number and that is fine, however how can I see or update this phone number from within the administrator's control panel? The home and mobile phone number fields do not seem to be present on any of the following screens where I would have expected to find them:

- Customers / Addresses - columns in this table view only include: first name, last name, address, postal code, city and country.
- Customers / Addresses / Edit - editable fields on this page only include: identification number, address alias, first name, last name, company, VAT number, address line 1, address line 2, city, country, postal code, country and a space for other information.
- Customers / Customers - columns in this table view only include: customer ID, social title, first name, last name, email address, sales total to date, enabled/disabled status, newsletter subscribed and opt-in status, user registration and last visited dates and times.
- Customers / Customers / Edit - editable fields on this page only include: social title, first name, last name, email address, birthday date, enabled/disabled status, newsletter subscribed and opt-in status, group access checkboxes and default customer group dropdown.

---

Update on 11-Jan-2017: After upgrading to Prestashop v1.6.1.10 the problem still remains with no changes to the above.

Comment: Under Customers / Addresses / Edit between Country and Other fields there are fields for Home and Mobile phone numbers. Maybe you have some customized admin templates in your shop that remove those fields?

Comment: @TheDrot Nope just using the default admin template installed with Prestashop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its not possible using Prestashop's default behaviour to view/edit customer phone numbers unless Prestashop is configured to include these in the address format, meaning they would also be shown in PDF's etc.

The work-around to this is to override the default behaviour, by creating a copy of `/controllers/admin/AdminAddressesController.php` in the `/override/controllers/admin` folder, adding the following lines to the function at line 198:

```
/* Start of override code by richhallstoke to enable viewing/editing of 
   customer phone numbers from within the administration panel without adding 
   them to the address format */
$addresses_fields[] = 'phone';
$addresses_fields[] = 'phone_mobile';
/* End of override code by richhallstoke
```

And then to make it take effect, force the automatic regeneration of `/cache/class_index.php` by simply deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Address fields are related directly with country address format.

Go to menu Clients -> Address -> Edit at the end before Others field phone fields are displayed. Once there look for the country of that specific address.

Then go to menu Localization -> Country, search for the previous country en click on Edit. On Address Format field make sure that phone and phone mobile are selected. If not, just add it and save changes.

That will be all. You should see that fields in Address Edit option. If you can't see it you must search for a change or override of this behavior in your shop source code.

Good luck.

Comment: There have been no changes to country-specific configuration relating to addresses but those phone fields are not displayed.

Comment: If I add them into Address Format will the mobile numbers appear on PDF invoices and delivery notes etc? They're not in that list at present.

Comment: If you change Format Address it will affect every place where an address is shown. Include it PDF. If this solved your problem, please mark it as valid. Good luck.

Comment: We don't want the phone numbers shown everywhere the address is shown, just want to see and edit customer phone numbers from the administration panel.

Comment: @PrestaAlba, you are my new god! Thanks! I didn't found this option anywhere!